# Sending UDP/TCP packets from server to clients

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp, firewall, nat

Ive build a local multiplayer game (multiplayer over wlan network). Now, I want to add an online multiplayer feature..
Currently, the network communications consist mostly of "signals" (tcp/udp packets sent from game-host peer to the game-client peers). I would like to use this mostly signal based communication for my online multiplayer (because of performance and efficiency ), too . But, since the host peer is now replaced by a server there will be a lot problems with sending signals (NAT, firewall,...).
So is there good solution to implement these signals?

regards

Answer (score 0):

> there will be a lot problems with sending signals (NAT, firewall,...)_

What problems exactly?

Normally, the clients establish a TCP connection to the server and the server uses this TCP connection to communicate with the clients.

For UDP-based communication the clients use [Internet Gateway Device Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) to forward ports on the router, so that the server can send UDP datagrams to the clients.

Comment: But I would like to send packets (UDP/TCP) from server to the clients. eg: sth. happens on server-side and the server sends a "signal" to all clients

Comment: @user2224350 So do that. What problem are you expecting exactly?

Comment: How should a server send an udp packet to a peer behind a nat router??
I'shouldt work

Comment: For some clients, UDP will work so long as the client sends the first packet. For some, it won't, and you'll have to use all TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server is in public internet, not behind any NAT. All the clients must initiate the connection. Otherwise the server can't know clients credential and can't connect. As the server has no NAT it will accept connection from client. And this connection client must keep alive. So when server needs to send some data there should be no problem.

This will work for both UDP and TCP.